# Node package searching for config properties of parent config files

Tags: node.js, npm, config

I have an custom node library repo (referring to it as "repo A"), which I use as an npm dependency in another node repo(this is the parent repo consuming repo A, referring to it as "repo B"). I'm using the "[config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config)" library in both of these repos. So I just added some properties in the config default.json of repo A. When I'm trying to access these values in the scripts of repo A, I realized that config library is looking for those values in the config json files of repo B(basically the parent repo). How do I stop this from happening, how do I say to the config library to look for the values in its own config json files, but not the parents'?

Comment: What config library?

Comment: @BrandonBuck, I updated my question with the hyperlink to the config npm package Im referring to

Comment: You can probably find your answer here: https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Configuration-Files